# Where does a bash process get its default signal handlers/traps?

Tags: linux, login, startup, signals, limit

From  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606753/do-getrlimit-and-setrlimit-work-by-reading-from-and-writing-to-etc-sec#comment88227414_50607042

> Bash doesn't have a special handler for SIGQUIT and is not involved in the process of creating a core dump. The kernel writes a core dump as part of the "default action" for SIGQUIT, if and only if the rlimit for core dumps is large enough; that rlimit may have been established by login according to what it says in limits.conf, or it may have been adjusted by hand using ulimit, or whatever.

I do not quite understand "Bash doesn't have a special handler for SIGQUIT".

Is it correct that every process has signal handlers even if some of them are default, and usually a process acquires its default signal handlers from `fork()` which will copies signal handlers from its parent, and `execve()` doesn't change signal handlers?

Where does a bash process get its default signal handlers/traps?

In APUE, I can't find whether `login` (or `getty` or some other program in starup sequence) is the first program which set up default signal handlers (as well as resource limits from `/etc/security/limits.conf`, which is the center of the topic in the link) and pass them down to the login shell:

> If we log in correctly, login will
>
> • Change to our home directory (chdir)
>
> • Change the ownership of our terminal device (chown) so we own it
>
> • Change the access permissions for our terminal device so we have
>   permission to read from and write to it
>
> • Set our group IDs by calling setgid and initgroups
>
> • Initialize  the  environment  with  all  the  information  that
>   login has:  our  home directory (HOME), shell (SHELL), user name (USER
>   and LOGNAME), and a default path (PATH)
>
> • Change to our user ID (setuid) and invoke our login shell, as in
>
> ```
> execl("/bin/sh", "-sh", (char *)0);
> ```

Comment: ["A child created via fork(2) inherits a copy of its parent's signal
       dispositions.  During an execve(2), the dispositions of handled
       signals are reset to the default; the dispositions of ignored signals
       are left unchanged."](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks. Is it possible that a process doesn't have a disposition for a signal? If that case after the process calls `execve()`, will the signal remain without a disposition?

Comment: There is always a disposition, even if it is the default as described under "Standard Signals".